# Replicate keyboard/mouse input to all virtualbox VMs

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have a few virtual box instances. Assuming they all have same resolutions, is there anyway to replicate mouse movement/clicks and keyboard presses to all VMs at the same time?

E.g. if I use my mouse to open Chrome in VM1, then the mouse in VM2 also moves accordingly and clicks on Chrome icon. If I key in `football` in VM1 then the same string is also keyed in into VM2.

My guest OS runs either Linux or Windows XP. I can upgrade to newer Windows versions but something lightweight is more preferable (since we are running multiple instances at the same time)

Comment: What host OS are you using?

Comment: @mtah Im on Linux, but I can install on Windows host if need be.